# Check if a document exists in Firebase Firestore, if not create a new

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How do I check if a document exists in Firebase Firestore, if not create a new one.

this is my code for now:

```
create(doc: any, collection: string): any {
  this.db.collection(collection, ref => ref.where('nome', '==', doc.nome))
    .snapshotChanges()
    .subscribe((ref: any) => {
      console.log('Ref = ', ref);
      if (ref.length <= 0) {
        this.db.collection(collection).add({ ...doc }).then(
          res => console.log('Inserido com sucesso : ', res)
        ).catch(err => console.log('Erro : ', err));
      }
      else {
        console.log('Evento ja existe : ', ref);
      }
    }).unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this question, it might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52277401/13058371 .... but the idea as the doc says: *If the document does not exist, it will be created. If the document does exist, its contents will be overwritten with the newly provided data*

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider using the `doc.nome` value as the document ID? If you do that, you won't need to use a query to find a document for the value, and can [use a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) to check-and-write atomically:

1. Start the transaction
2. Read the document
3. If it doesn't exist yet, write the document
4. Commit the transaction

Also see:

- [Can we not query collections inside transactions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50071700/can-we-not-query-collections-inside-transactions)